# Hacer array a partir de consulta PHP para mostrar los resultados en HTML

Tags: php

Esto aclara un poco más la anterior pregunta que no pude solucionar. Quiero formatear bien la salida de una consulta SQL para poder mostrar después los resultados en una página HTML. El gestor de DB es **Postgresql 9.2** . Después de hacer la consulta el resultado que me muestra es redundante en algunos campos, condicionado porque para un mismo ID hay almacenas varias imágenes o los propietarios de las imágenes son distintos, pondré el resultado que muestra la consulta para que veáis a lo que me refiero.
La **consulta** la hago **a varias tablas: vl_spezies, vw_spezies, vl_images**

```
$especie=!empty($_GET['elemento']) ? $_GET['elemento'] : NULL;

$sql = "SELECT
             vl_spezies.aphia_id_code,vw_spezies.id_spezie, vw_spezies.aphia_id_code, vw_spezies.x3a_code, vw_spezies.scientific_name, vw_spezies.description, vl_images.autor, vl_images.principal, vl_images.path_system::text || vl_images.name_original::text AS imagen 
        FROM 
            vw_spezies, vl_images, vl_spezies
        WHERE 
            vl_spezies.aphia_id_code = vw_spezies.aphia_id_code and vw_spezies.id_spezie = :id and vl_images.aphia_id_code = vw_spezies.aphia_id_code 
        ORDER BY vw_spezies.aphia_id_code";
            
$statement = $cnn->prepare($sql);
$params = array(":id"=>$especie);
$valor = $statement->execute($params);
    
if( $valor ){
        
    while( $resultado = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $data["data"][] = $resultado;
    }
//hago un var_dump para ver que me muestra
var_dump($data);    
}else{
    echo ("error");
}
```

El resultado que me muestra después de hacer el var_dump

```
array(1){
  [
    "data"
  ]=>array(3){
    [
      0
    ]=>array(8){
      [
        "aphia_id_code"
      ]=>int(126554)[
        "id_spezie"
      ]=>int(211)[
        "x3a_code"
      ]=>string(3)"ANK"[
        "scientific_name"
      ]=>string(17)"Lophius budegassa"[
        "description"
      ]=>string(40)"Cuerpo muy deprimido, cabeza muy grande."[
        "autor"
      ]=>string(15)"Andrés Martinez"[
        "principal"
      ]=>bool(false)[
        "imagen"
      ]=>string(49)"https://servidor.es/img/Lophius_budegassa_003.jpg"
    }[
      1
    ]=>array(8){
      [
        "aphia_id_code"
      ]=>int(126554)[
        "id_spezie"
      ]=>int(211)[
        "x3a_code"
      ]=>string(3)"ANK"[
        "scientific_name"
      ]=>string(17)"Lophius budegassa"[
        "description"
      ]=>string(40)"Cuerpo muy deprimido, cabeza muy grande."[
        "autor"
      ]=>string(16)"Carlos Fernández"[
        "principal"
      ]=>bool(false)[
        "imagen"
      ]=>string(49)"https://servidor.es/img/Lophius_budegassa_002.jpg"
    }[
      2
    ]=>array(8){
      [
        "aphia_id_code"
      ]=>int(126554)[
        "id_spezie"
      ]=>int(211)[
        "x3a_code"
      ]=>string(3)"ANK"[
        "scientific_name"
      ]=>string(17)"Lophius budegassa"[
        "description"
      ]=>string(40)"Cuerpo muy deprimido, cabeza muy grande."[
        "autor"
      ]=>string(16)"Carlos Fernández"[
        "principal"
      ]=>bool(true)[
        "imagen"
      ]=>string(49)"https://servidor.es/img/Lophius_budegassa_001.jpg"
    }
  }
}
```

Como veis hasta la Clave "autor" los valores son únicos, pero en las claves autor, principal e imagen, puede haber varios valores distintos. Respecto a la CLAVE principal, siempre va a haber una que es TRUE, pude haber un propietario de imagen con varias imágenes, o varios propietarios con varias imágenes. En el ejemplo hay 3 imágenes y dos propietarios.

Me gustaría sacar una especie de ficha en la que salieran los datos. Saldría la imagen principal con el nombre del autor y debajo las otras imágenes con sus respectivos nombres. Algo así, más o menos.

```
<!-- aphia id code e id_spezie van ocultos -->
<div class="galeria" id="ficha">
    <div class = "fichas">
        <div class = "cuerpo">
            <div class="cuerpoSup">
                <div class="ImgEspecie">
                    <div class="rowDesFlag0">
                        <div class="text-title-flag scieflag"></div><!-- x3a code -->
                        <div class="text-title-flag scieflag" id="text-flag"></div><!-- scientific name -->
                    </div>
                    <ul class="flags">
                        <li id="IMGprincipal"></li><!-- Nombre Imagen Principal -->
                        <li class="sub"><span class="bold"><i class="fas fa-camera cameras">&nbsp;</i></span><span class="text-camera" id="author"></span></li><!-- Nombre Autor -->
                    </ul>
                    <div class = "galeriaImg">
                        <ul id="peques"></ul><!-- Nombre resto imágenes -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="divDescripcion">
                <div class="descripcion">
                    <div id="descripcion"></div><!-- descripcion -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

salida haciendo un json_encode

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "aphia_id_code": 126554,
      "id_spezie": 211,
      "x3a_code": "ANK",
      "scientific_name": "Lophius budegassa",
      "description": "Cuerpo muy deprimido, cabeza muy grande.",
      "autor": "Andrés Martinez",
      "principal": false,
      "imagen": "https://servidor.es/img/Lophius_budegassa_003.jpg"
    },
    {
      "aphia_id_code": 126554,
      "id_spezie": 211,
      "x3a_code": "ANK",
      "scientific_name": "Lophius budegassa",
      "description": "Cuerpo muy deprimido, cabeza muy grande.",
      "autor": "Carlos Fernández ",
      "principal": false,
      "imagen": "https://servidor.es/img/Lophius_budegassa_002.jpg"
    },
    {
      "aphia_id_code": 126554,
      "id_spezie": 211,
      "x3a_code": "ANK",
      "scientific_name": "Lophius budegassa",
      "description": "Cuerpo muy deprimido, cabeza muy grande.",
      "autor": "Carlos Fernández",
      "principal": true,
      "imagen": "https://servidor.es/img/Lophius_budegassa_001.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Demasiado bien no esta, pero bueno, se entiende. Lo que no se entiende es que vale, ahora ya tienes un array con todos los datos, no te hace falta más arrays supongo, ¿y cual es el problema?

Comment: Vale, una ficha... ¿y el html de la ficha lo puedes poner en la pregunta?  Es para ayudarte mejor, pues si tengo que teclearlo todo va a ser que no.

Comment: No veo como distingues la imagen principal. Es decir, en el array conseguido parece que todas son imagenes principales, pero el autor se repite

Comment: error de edición! culpa mía.  Lo ejecuté varias veces para varias especies y al hacer el copy/paste se me quedó. Siempre va a haber una principal a TRUE y el resto a FALSE

Comment: No, creo que ha sido culpa mia, malinterpreté ese booleano, vamos, lo omití (es que el var_dump nunca me ha gustado, yo lo entiendo todo mejor con el print_r a pesar que le falte info)

Comment: Y el orden de salida de las fichas?  Por nombre de autor?

Comment: Si la imagen es principal, la muestro en grande y las que no sean principales las muestro como thumbs, entonces sería por imagen, no?

Comment: Pensaba que querias mostrar varias fichas de autores a la vez, pero tal como lo dices es solo una cada vez, cierto?

Comment: En el formulario envías el id de la especie, y una vez ejecutada la consulta se muestra una ficha del bicho en cuestión con todos los datos de la tabla. El problema es que puede tener varias imágenes y varios autores, de ahí que pensara en poner una imagen como principal y las otras como miniaturas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poniéndolo todo en el mismo sitio deberia ser algo asi:

```php
// inicializamos variables
$imagenes = [];
$autores = [];
$datos_unicos = [];

// recorremos datos
while( $resultado = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $datos_unicos = $resultado;
    if(!in_array($resultado['autor'], $autores)) {
       $autores[] = $resultado['autor'];
    }
    if($resultado['principal'] == true) {
        $imagenes['img_principal'] = $resultado['imagen'];
        $imagenes['autor_img_principal'] = $resultado['autor'];
    } else {
        if (isset($resultado['imagen']) and !empty($resultado['imagen'])) {
            $imagenes[$resultado['autor']]['imagenes'][] = $resultado['imagen'];
        }
    }
}

// generamos inicio salida
$salidaHTML = '
<div class="galeria" id="ficha">
    <div class = "fichas">
        <div class = "cuerpo">
            <div class="cuerpoSup">
                <div class="ImgEspecie">
                    <div class="rowDesFlag0">
                        <div class="text-title-flag scieflag">'.$datos_unicos['x3a_code'].'</div><!-- x3a code -->
                        <div class="text-title-flag scieflag" id="text-flag">'.$datos_unicos['scientific_name'].'</div><!-- scientific name -->
                    </div>
                    <ul class="flags">
                        <li id="IMGprincipal"><img src="'.$imagenes['img_principal'].'"></li><!-- Nombre Imagen Principal -->
                        <li class="sub"><span class="bold"><i class="fas fa-camera cameras">&nbsp;</i></span><span class="text-camera" id="author">'.$imagenes['autor_img_principal'].'</span></li><!-- Nombre Autor -->
                    </ul>
                    <div class = "galeriaImg">
                        <ul id="peques">
                        </ul><!-- Nombre resto imágenes -->';

// recorremos autores e imagenes secundarias
foreach($autores as $autor) {
    if(isset($imagenes[$autor]['imagenes'])) {
        foreach($imagenes[$autor]['imagenes'] as $secundaria) {
            // agregamos imagenes secundarias
            $salidaHTML .= '
                            <li><img src="'.$secundaria.'" alt="Autor: '.$autor.'"></li>';
        }
    }
}

// cerramos salida
$salidaHTML .= '
                        </ul><!-- Nombre resto imágenes -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="divDescripcion">
                <div class="descripcion">
                    <div id="descripcion">'.$datos_unicos['description'].'</div><!-- descripcion -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
';

// imprimimos salida 
echo $salidaHTML;
```

Comment: creo que en parte lo he solucionado @masterguru Lo que hice fue relacionarlo a un id en lugar de al autor. Me falta el "punch" porque si solamente tiene img principal sale el Notice de Undefined index: imágenes y el warning del foreach(). Faltaría que contemplara que puede haber solamente imagen principal y no más imágenes, de ese modo no fallaría. https://pastebin.com/stXupyqi

Comment: Vale, ya esta, recarga la página, copia el código y prueba de nuevo cuando regreses

Comment: Correcto!! @masterguru

Comment: acabo de detectar @masterguru en una ficha que tiene 2 autores y 3 fotos, 1 autor  tiene una IMG principal y otra secundaria, pues pinta la principal del autor, pinta la secundaria, después pinta la secundaria del segundo autor, y a continuación vuelve a pintar la secundaria del primer autor que ya había pintado, repite la img del autor que tiene img principal. Hago un var_dump y solo salen tres imágenes en el array, pongo el pastebin  https://pastebin.com/iUjSVgxD

Comment: Supongo que es porque se ha repetido un autor por lo que sea durante el recorrido de la consulta... acabo de modificar mi respuesta agregando esto: `if(!in_array($resultado['autor'], $autores)) {
       $autores[] = $resultado['autor'];
    }` en lugar de esto solo: `$autores[] = $resultado['autor'];`.  A ver si ahora te funciona ese caso. De este modo los autores no se repiten en ese array `$autores`.

Comment: Correcto!!! Ahora lo hace sin problema.

Comment: Bien, una cosa menos :-)  Aun así, eso se debe a que la consulta tampoco debe estar muy fina, pero mientras consigamos arreglarlo con PHP y funcione ya esta bien